# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in powershell

Tags: powershell, null

I am running below powershell command but getting error as below

```
$Username = "xxxxxxxxx
$Password = "Pxxxxxxxxx"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server-Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {

Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
Get-QADGroup -Identity "Account Operators" -Service DomainName  }
```

ERROR:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-QADGroup], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.GetGroupCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : eabp01ts04
```

Comment: Is that the only error thrown?

Comment: Does this [Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement] even exist on that remote host? If not then that first must be corrected. Also, this [$Username = "xxxxxxxxx], shoudl be this [$Username = "xxxxxxxxx"] or this.. [$Username = 'xxxxxxxxx']. Also, never put plain text crdentials scripts. Bad practice, and uneeded risk. especially for ADDS stuff. ALways prompt, [$creds = Get-Credential] , then use the variable or store teo secure file, or Windows Credential Manager and call from there.

Comment: Yes the [Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement] is present on remote host .

Comment: Yes the [Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement] is present on remote host and get this only error .
When I run get-Qadgroupmember command directly on the remote host I get the desired output , only when I run it remotely using invoke command I get this error .